# Are trans-Planckian field values a problem for the relaxion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

The [relaxion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07551) is a new model-building gadget that solves the hierarchy problem by allowing the Higgs mass term to dynamically relax to zero.

To describe it as simply as possible, leaving a lot out: we let $a$ be the QCD axion and set
$$\mathcal{L} \supset (-M_0^2 + ga) |h|^2.$$
The Higgs mass term is hence small if we can get $ga = M_0^2$ dynamically. We give the axion a linear potential and allow it to slow roll during inflation. When the Higgs mass term becomes negative, the usual sinusoidal potential for the axion turns on because the quarks gain mass, trapping $a$ at this critical value.

One of the apparent flaws of the relaxion is that the potential for $a$ must be extremely flat for this to work, which in turn requires the field values of $a$ to be huge; they are greater than $1$ in Planck units. This makes it seem like complicated quantum gravity effects should come into play.

However, I'm not sure why this is. It's true that a trans-Planckian energy density would bring in quantum gravity effects, but here it's just the *field value* that's large. The energy density is not large, because the potential is very flat. The particular field value doesn't even sound like a physical quantity, since I can always do a field redefinition $a \to a - a_0$.

Is there really something wrong with a field value above the Planck scale? If so, exactly what is it?

Comment: *The energy density is not large, because the potential is very flat.* – Could you please turn this into a precise statement by maybe providing the relevant stress energy tensor and explaining why its components are small compared to the Planck scale?

Comment: One argument against super-Planckian field excursions comes from effective field theory: an effective field theory description of inflation involves an effective
potential for the inflaton of the form $$V(\phi) = V_0 + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 + \phi^4\sum_{p=0}^\infty \lambda_p\left(\frac{\phi}{m_{\rm Pl}}\right)^p.$$ The terms with $p>0$ have couplings with negative mass dimension and so are non-renormalizable. As long as $\phi \ll m_{\rm Pl}$ these terms can be kept under control and the above series is at least asymptotically convergent.